# Device picker gone in Xcode

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan, xcode6.4

My device picker at the top of my Xcode window has disappeared. I'm running Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan. This means that I can only run my app on an iPhone 6 simulator. I can't even port my app to my phone to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4 is not supported on El Capitan.  You should be running the Xcode 7 betas on El Capitan.

The simulators that are present in Xcode 6.x will not work in El Capitan.  You might want to delete /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Runtimes if they contain the older runtimes downloaded through Xcode 6.

El Capitan Beta 4 and El Capitan Beta 5 have a [release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/) about this:

> Xcode processes may quit unexpectedly if older iOS Simulator runtimes
>   (Xcode 6.x) are present on disk

While CoreSimulatorService is unable to start (due to the bug that is triggered by the older runtimes), you won't see simulator devices in Xcode's run destinations menu.